# How to combine queryset via ManyToManyField in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build an Instagram clone.
I need to pass user's posts and follow's to the dashboard.

The dashboard is received posts whose owner is the requesting user.

I'd like to combine posts written by the user who requested it with posts by other users who were followed by the user for ordering posts.

But I don't know how to

I am not sure you understand what i mean. Sorry about my english.

## For example.

User1 has posts

```
(title='First', created_at='19-01-01', author='user1')
(title='Third', created_at='19-01-03', author='user1')
```

User2 has a post

```
(title='Second' created_at='19-01-02', author='user2')
```

and user1 follow user2.

And then If user1 access his dashboard.
The dashboard shows you posts like this below.

```
(title='First', created_at='19-01-01', author='user1')
(title='Second' created_at='19-01-02', author='user2')
(title='Third', created_at='19-01-03', author='user1')
```

models.py

```py
class Insta(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/', blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True, default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    user_fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnail/')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)
```

views.py

```py
 def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('insta:signup')
        else:
            user = request.user
            response = Insta.objects.filter(owner=user.id)
            return Response({'posts': response, 'user': user})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is hard to know what you mean: Maybbe you can give an example with some data

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Have you tried this `Insta.objects.filter(Q(owner=user) | Q(owner__in=user.follows.all()))` ? one disadvantage here is as follows increases it would affect the performance since it is an IN query